# Faster way to select different sections of dataframe than a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of instacart orders

```
order_id    product_id  add_to_cart_order   reordered   product_name    
32          49683       7                   1           Cucumber Kirby  
52          49683       4                   1           Cucumber Kirby  
88          49683       20                  0           Cucumber Kirby  
95          49683       12                  1           Cucumber Kirby  
111         49683       5                   1           Cucumber Kirby
```

reordered is either 1 or 0 indicating whether the customer had ordered that product in a previous order or not.

I want to get info on a per-product basis, for example I would like to know which products have the most number of reorders (among other things). The only way I can think of to do this is to iterate through the dataframe, selecting only rows by product name one at a time, and summing the values of reordered for each product. Only problem is there are about 92k different products and this is breaking my computer and taking forever. Here's my code. I'm saving the results to a dictionary but I'm open to other approaches. There must be a more efficient way to do this?

```
reordersums = {}
for product in list(products.product_name):
# Select the rows whose product name matches the product we are checking, sum the values in column "reordered"
    reordersum = order_products[order_products.product_name == product].reordered.sum()

    reordersums[product]=reordersum    
print(reordersums)
```

Comment: df[df.reordered==1].groupby('product_name').sum()

This should work. Give it a try Sam or if it doesn't, can you share the sample data to perform some analysis.

Comment: @ Sam, see the answer if that's what you are looking for , or you can update your post with desired result.

Comment: @AmitAmola Ah yes, groupby, how could I forget. Your one line of code is simple, elegant, and gave me exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Shall i add it as an answer and you can give an upvote? Haha @Sam

Comment: @SamRheault, but  make sure this will not work if your `reordered` count is more than one So better to use filter with lambda in case value goes `1 (==1)` or `2` or any higher .

Comment: @AmitAmola,  I believe user need to have at least 15 point as a reputation to upvote the hence Sam will not be able to upvote rather you can upvote :-)

Comment: Sam was the one who asked the question... So I am referring to him accepting my comment as an answer if I post it as an answer @pygo... But seems like he has already accepted yours .. haha... No worries

Comment: @AmitAmola, but as i said that answer will fail if the `reordering` will have more than number one , it looks only for `==1`  condition & don't  take  `> 1` expression though.

Comment: I don't think reordered will ever have any other value beside 0 or 1. It's either yes(1) or no(0). Don't you think mate? Well only Sam can confirm this 

Comment: Hey guys sorry, @Amit if yours was an answer I would have accepted it, but yes I can't upvote because I am new.

Comment: @pygo reordered is only ever 1 or 0, indicating yes or no if the customer has ordered the product in the past. But thanks for thinking robustly ;)

Comment: No issues mate... have a lovely year ahead :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below, However i'm not sure it this is what you are looking for:

**Your illustrated DataFrame Structure:**

```
   order_id  product_id  add_to_cart_order  reordered    product_name
0        32       49683                  7          1  Cucumber Kirby
1        52       49683                  4          1  Cucumber Kirby
2        88       49683                 20          0  Cucumber Kirby
3        95       49683                 12          1  Cucumber Kirby
4       111       49683                  5          1  Cucumber Kirby
```

**Solution:**  groupby + DataFrame.filter + sum()

```
>>> df.groupby('reordered').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).groupby(['product_name']).sum().reset_index()
     product_name  order_id  product_id  add_to_cart_order  reordered
0  Cucumber Kirby       290      198732                 28          4
```

**OR** , as suggested by @Amit in comment Section.

```
>>> df[df.reordered==1].groupby('product_name').sum().reset_index()
     product_name  order_id  product_id  add_to_cart_order  reordered
0  Cucumber Kirby       290      198732                 28          4
```

**OR** , In case you want only to see `product_name` & `reordered`

```
df.set_index('product_name').reordered.ge(1).sum(level=0).astype(int).reset_index()
     product_name  reordered
0  Cucumber Kirby          4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [group_by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) interface:

```
# Group up the dataframe by product
group_products = products.groupby('product_name')

# Sum the groups on the reordered column
reordered_sums = group_products['reordered'].agg('sum')
```